# Loop through range in either direction in javascript

Tags: javascript, modulus

I'm looking for a simplified way of achieving the following goal:

> Loop through the range `0 to x` in either direction, where x is any positive number.

The following is what I have so far using `modulus`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify it even further?

Increase:

`v = (v + 1) % total`

Decrease:

`v = v ? (v - 1) % x : x - 1`

Comment: Ah, ok. The edit hadn't shown up for me yet when I typed mine.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if you can write it as an answer I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The increase pseudo-code is already fully simplified, however, you can simplify the logic for your decrease in one of two ways:

```
v = v ? v - 1 : x - 1
```

or

```
v = (v + x - 1) % x
```

The former is valid because you know the decrement will never need to be modulated to be in the range `[0, x)`, but the latter approach is preferred because it avoids unnecessary branching logic.

Keep in mind though, as an edge-case, if `x` is over half of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2**53 - 1), the first approach is the only one that will work as expected.